# PostgreSQL: check if row exists and if created 10 minutes ago

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a query in postgres that acts like this:

```
if row exists in table AND created_time <= '10 minutes'
 update the row

else
  insert new row
```

the query keeps insert new row even if it's exist in table. this is the query I wrote:

```
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM tbl WHERE id = _id) AND (SELECT FROM tbl WHERE created_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL '10 MINUTE') THEN
    UPDATE public.tbl_client_location
    SET value=_value, updated_date=now()
    WHERE id = _id;
ELSE
   INSERT INTO tbl (id, value)
    VALUES (
                _id,
                _value
           )
    RETURNING id INTO _id;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: you missed the id in the second part of the query   EXISTS (SELECT FROM tbl WHERE id = _id) AND (SELECT FROM tbl WHERE  id = _id and created_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL '10 MINUTE') THEN

Comment: if I try to insert for example row with id 1 and immediatly try to insert again with the same id it's still insert a new row instead of updating the row that already exists

Comment: @OfirSasson Not sure what you mean by that comment, but you can't update a record with INSERT, you have to use UPDATE... And if you don't get errors while trying to insert a row with the same ID then your ID field is not unique.

Comment: Why do you use two SELECT statements? From your description I would have expected `if exists (select * from tbl where id = _id AND created_date <=...) then`

Comment: I think that I need to do some sort of upsert using conflict but I'm not sure how because I need to ask about two conditions, if there's already row with this id and if yes, check if the created time is with the 10 minutes interval (after 10 minutes do not update)

Answer (score 1):

Do not bother to check, let Postgres do the checking. Use the `on conflict do update` which contains a `where` that only processes the appropriate rows. Something like: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d209c77d5369e7a7b2f90409a1c346e0))

```
insert into tbl(id, value) 
    values (id, value) 
 on conflict (id) 
 do update 
      set value = excluded.value
    where now() - interval '10 min' < attm;
```